# Facebook login and authorization shows friends, can that be removed?

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization

In the facebook login dialog, when users have to authorize the app, it shows something like "1 friend and 6 other people are using this app."

Id like to not show that information on that screen, is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to NOT show friends using an app in the auth dialog?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10936553/is-there-a-way-to-not-show-friends-using-an-app-in-the-auth-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are no documented parameters for that, neither in the [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) call nor in the [FB.init()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) call nor in the [Login URL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/), I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Indeed. I am however using the PHP SDK, not the javascript SDK. But there is hardly any documentation for the PHP SDK, most links to sites are no longer alive.